# Python: raw_input and unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, operands, exponent

I am a newbie to Python and have been recently attempting to create a BMI calculator, but I am having errors with the following code:

```
def calculator():

    weight = raw_input('Please enter your weight (kg):')

    if weight.isdigit and weight > 0:
        height = raw_input('Please enter your height (m):') 

        if height.isdigit and height > 0:
            bmi = (weight) / (height ** 2) 

            print "Your BMI is", bmi

            if bmi < 18.5:
                print 'You are underweight.'
            if bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25:
                print 'Your BMI is normal.'
            if bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30:
                print 'You are overweight.'
            if bmi >= 30:
                print 'You are obese.'      

        else:   
            height = raw_input('Please state a valid number (m):')


    else:
        weight = raw_input('Please state a valid number (kg):')
```

Whenever I try to execute the code, I am able to enter weight and height, but I am then confronted with this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*location*", line 40, in <module>
    calculator()
  File "*location*", line 15, in calculator
    bmi = (weight) / (height ** 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

I apologize for this dumb question and error-ridden code, but I am very new to programming and appreciate any kind of help. :)

Comment: things you get from `raw_input` are always in string type convert them to int using `int()`

Comment: Note that `weight.isdigit` only references the method, it doesn't actually *call* that method.

Comment: there are  many error in your program just go through the basic of python then try again and what are you trying to accomplish here  `if height == exit:`

Comment: @VigneshKalai Kind of funny. You and me pointed at the same error at the same time. :)

Comment: @sam2090 :) it happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` always returns a `str` object. You need to explicitly convert the input to an `int`.
You can either do

```
val = int(raw_input(...))
```

or

```
val = raw_input(...)
val = int(val)
```

As others have mentioned, there are many errors in your code. Here is one:

```
if height == exit:
```

Same problem with `weight` condition. I am just going to point out as you didn't ask about this in question so I will let you find out what the problem is :).

Answer (score 2):

Please use it this way

```
def calculator():

    weight = int(raw_input('Please enter your weight (kg):'))

    if weight >0 and weight > 0:
        height = int(raw_input('Please enter your height (m):')) 

        if height >0 and height > 0:
            bmi = (weight) / (height ** 2) 

            print "Your BMI is", bmi

            if bmi < 18.5:
                print 'You are underweight.'
            if bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25:
                print 'Your BMI is normal.'
            if bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30:
                print 'You are overweight.'
            if bmi >= 30:
                print 'You are obese.'      

        else:   
            height = int(raw_input('Please state a valid number (m):'))
        if height == exit:
            exit()

    else:
        weight = int(raw_input('Please state a valid number (kg):'))

    if weight == exit:
        exit()
```

You need to cast input entries to int because they are strings.

And you no longer have to check if it is a digit,

Still, I suggest you add another condition like:

```
if weight and height:
    #Do stuff
```

In case no entry was provided.

EDIT:

/!\ In case you need decimals cast them to float

Answer (score 1):

the numbers entered should be converted to float. just change the
bmi = float(weight)/(float(height)** 2)
You are good to go